# Solr Query and Full String Matching

Tags: solr

I'm currently working on a program that sends queries against a Solr service and I'm hanging on a problem with how Solr matches strings.

For example when I'm sending MaterialType:buc, it matches all entries with MaterialType = "buc" and with "ebuc" aswell. Is there anything I can do to tell Solr that I want an exact match only (or that it should match only strings that start with "buc")?

Is this even possible without changing the configuration of the solr service?

Regards
Tobias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How the match is performed depends on how your field is defined. You're probably querying against a TextField with an analysis chain attached that decomposes the terms `buc` and `ebuc` down to the same term (such as by using a `EdgeNGramFilter` or a stemming filter, etc.).

You can either use a `StrField` directly (which will only give you exact matches, case sensitivity and all), or you use a TextField with a KeywordTokenizer (which leaves the whole term intact) and only apply a LowercaseFilter to make the match case insensitive.

If you want to prefix match, you can append a "*" after your query for a StrField, or you can use one of the ngramfilters and only apply the ngram from the beginning of the token.

All these changes would need to be applied to your schema (schema.xml) and your content would normally have to be reindexed after the schema has changed.

Comment: That's what I feared since I don't have access to the server :(

Comment: @TobiasZimmermann Check the list of fields - maybe there's another field available that contains the same information and that is not processed.